# Create many graphs in neo4j 3.0

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, py2neo

How to create two graphs on the same database. In fact, I modelized my problem using two graphs and I need to compare time execution to choose the better one. I'm using pyn2eo to generate both graphs.

Thank you for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database contains only one graph. You can store your data in the same database and separate the two subgraphs with labels or some other naming convention.

A neo4j server can only run one database at a time. However, you can set the database location in the `neo4j.conf` file. You could run neo4j, store the first graph, stop neo4j, set a new database location, start again and store the second graph in the new database.

The setting is `dbms.active_database`, see http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/